# My flag was declined on an answer that didn't answer the question

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15537849/1156119) the yesterday while I was trying to solve my own issues building my Android project. I flagged it as needing moderator attention, while it meets the criteria for "not an answer" I put it under "other" so I could give some clarification on what I meant as it probably would not have been obvious to someone who was not familiar with the domain. Here is my message:

> The answer doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question, it also doesn't even suggest any real answer.

The response I got was a little unexpected:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

I wouldn't flag a wrong answer if the user thought it was right as that's what voting is for. This answer doesn't seem to even belong in the question, the answerer seems to indicate that he could build and run his application however the question is about not being able to run the project at all as an .apk (installer) cannot be generated by the IDE.

The question is really filling up with noise and I was flagging to clear this completely irrelevant answer up for future visitors. This answer really seemed to satisfy the requirements for flagging for moderator attention:

> it needs ♦ moderator attention
>
> not an answer
>
> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Can somebody clarify what would be a good candidate if this was not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There were six other flags on that answer, all "not an answer" flags; a moderator (other than the one who declined your flag) finally deleted it.

It's clear that the community did not like the answer at all, but the answer does suggest an action that apparently worked for the answerer, and there's no other clarification in the comments from the community as to why they didn't like it.

This is the text of the answer:

> I was following a tutorial for AndEngine, but left in the onCreate()
>   method that a typical activity uses.  Removing the method didn't
>   eliminate the error, but the game actually finished going through the
>   motions, drawing graphics to the screen and whatnot.

Looking at the question, you are right; the answer does not appear to have anything to do with the question.  In the strictest letter of the law, it does, in fact require a bit of technical knowledge to figure out.  The most likely possibility seems to be that the answerer posted his answer *on the wrong question.*

Keep in mind that the community flags hundreds of Stack Overflow posts each day; if I can't figure out a custom flag on an answer in less than 30 seconds or so, I'm more likely than not to dismiss the flag without taking any action on the post.

Moral of the story: moderators are not perfect.